# On Android Studio is there a simple way of getting the distance and time between two markers?

Tags: android, location, google-maps-markers, google-distancematrix-api

Below is my Maps Activity for one of my locations. At the bottom of the code I have attempted to calculate the distance between two markers. So that when i run it, it will appear on the map. Is there a simple way of doing this as the way Ive dont it is not working. Thanks

```
package com.example.aids.gettingtherepage;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class FromBelfastCity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_from_belfast_city);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng BelfastCity = new LatLng(54.6176, -5.8718);
        LatLng BelfastCityCentre = new LatLng(54.607868, -5.926437);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BelfastCity).title("Belfast City Airport"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BelfastCityCentre).title("Belfast City Centre"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(BelfastCity));


        float[] results = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(BelfastCity.latitude, BelfastCity.longitude,
                BelfastCityCentre.latitude, BelfastCityCentre.longitude,
                results);
    }
}
```

This is the output below:

The two markers are plotted on google maps. However they are not connected and there is no directions distance/time.

[The output I get on the emulator is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oHT9.jpg)

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it is not working" means.

Comment: Done. Ive added an image

Comment: You have no code that connects those markers, and you have no code for showing "directions distance/time". A Google search for `android maps v2 directions` turns up some possibilities for how to do that, such as [this blog post](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/). Personally, I haven't implemented these features, and so I do not know if the details from that post are accurate or not.